# Varstatus Index not working for adf iterator

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have an iterator loop for whose children I'm using varStatus for id. When I run the below code, it does not show any value and the id becomes "lkextres_" with no index value appended.

```
<af:iterator value="#{sessionScope.appBB.resourceList}" var="resourceDef" id="itrResourceList" varStatus="vs">
      <af:link id="lkextres_#{vs.index}" useWindow="true" immediate="true" />
</af:iterator>
```

Please help with how do I get index values to put in id. My purpose is to have different id for each child element so i am using varstatus in af:iterator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set id of a component/tag inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147771/how-can-i-set-id-of-a-component-tag-inside-uirepeat)

Comment: Varstatus index is most likely working fine, just not for assigning id. And normally the id is already automatically postfixed.